# Using JQuery with Django base.html template

Tags: jquery, django

I'm using Django-1.4.5. and JQuery and I have problem with templating system: I have base.html with script and JQuery functions, but when I try to use tabs in another template (which extends base.html), it doesn't show up. Here is my base.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#accordion1").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
    });
    $('#accordion2').accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
    })
    $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
    $("#tabs-li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
});
```

And my other template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Tab 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1"><p>Text 1</p></div>
    <div id="tab2"><p>Text 2</p></div> 
    <div id="tab3"><p>Text 3</p></div>
    <div id="tab4"><p>Text 4</p></div>
    <div id="tab5"><p>Text 5</p></div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I switch tabs in base.html, it works without problems. I can't  figure out why it doesn't work when I extend base.html. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I would recommend using the [`staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) app to use the `static` template tag instead of `{{ STATIC_URL }}`, which is less flexible.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on "it doesn't work". No body shown at all? Just Javascript/jQuery not converting this divs into tabs? Does the page source meet your expectations? Any Javascript console errors in your browser? Any Django errors? etc.

Comment: by any chance did you find a solution to this problem? I am working on django, and the jquery works the base template and for some weird reason in index.html template. But the jquery code does not work in the other pages that extends base.html template

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in your base.html, can you write that?

maybe you are re writing the head with `{% block head %}{% endblock %}` in your template ?

Comment: My content in base.html is in the <body> tag (I have two accordions), and script in <head> tag. I use {% block content %}{% endblock %} only in this other template, end it is empty, as you can see.

Comment: @Gogo There's no `content` block in your base.html template you included in your question. Defining one in a template extending it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
```

you're trashing all the content in the `head` block in the `base.html`. I guess that your `base.html` template is enclosing all javascript sources in this block.

Just leave out these two lines. The `head` block will be inherited.

Comment: No, I tried already. The result is the same with or without head block.